# Why do I get a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on the second line here?

Tags: java, substring

Why does the following Java code snippet throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on the third line of code?

```
String str = "1234567890";
String sub1 = str.substring(0, 3);
String sub2 = str.substring(4, 1);
```

I'd have expected the result of the above code to be that sub1 contains "123" and sub2 contains "5", but instead I get the exception mentioned above. Does the first substring call have have side-effect on the string being operated on?

Comment: Are you serious? And Strings are immutable.

Comment: Yeah, now that I know the answer, it seems like a pretty silly question. I have 2 weeks Java experience, after many years using other languages, all of which take startIndex and length as the params to their respective substring functions. Add that to the fact that I was porting code from a similar language which used the params as I expressed, hopefully you'll see how I overlooked such an obvious bug. My cardinal sin was not referring to the docs for substring. What can I say? Its been a long week :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `beginIndex` is larger than `endIndex`

See the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

**Throws:**
*IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or* ***beginIndex*** *is* ***larger*** *than* ***endIndex.***

Comment: Ah! My bad. Coming from another language I thought I was passing in beginIndex, count. Thanks for de-mystifying my Friday :-)

Comment: Yeap, I would think that also. Like 1 char after the 4th element ... right?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) : `String.substring(beginIndex,endIndex)`

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of the method `substring()` is the index of the beginning of your selection, and the second is the index of the end, not the length you want your selection to be as you apparently think.

See the documentation [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).